# git - multiple .gitmodules files

Tags: git, git-submodules

Within my git repository I added a third party library as a submodule to a dedicated sub folder '/Workspace/Common/Lib/External'. Therefore on repository root level there exists one '.gitmodules' file with all required information.

Now I noticed that the library itself also uses a submodule. Therefore a second '.gitmodules' file is located at '/Workspace/Common/Lib/External' level.

From my point of view only the root level '.gitmodules' file is used by git. So it is unclear for me how to handle multiple '.gitmodules' files. Is it required to add the libraries submodule to my repository per hand (git submodule add...) or is there some .gitmodules merge functionality available ?

Answer (score 1):

A submodule may have its own submodules thus making a tree of submodules. That's why many commands that work with submodules have option `--recursive`. See [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).